# Couchbase: Timeout via Spring Boot Data Couchbase but fast (expected) response via Workbench

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, sql++

System environment:

Couchbase Server: Enterprise 5.5.1
Spring Boot Starter Parent: 2.0.5.RELEASE
Spring Boot Data Couchbase: 3.0.10.RELEASE

--

I have a strange issue and can’t figure out what the reason might be here.

There is a single couchbase bucket which contains about 52M docs and I created an index for a rather long/complex query (array checks and multiple ranges). The index size is about 1.6G disk size and 1.1G data size with approx. 14M items indexed.

The execution of the exact same n1ql query runs into a timeout (set to 25s) when calling it via the Spring Boot Backend (where the n1ql is configured in the repo). But in the workbench, the execution time is about 400ms using the exact same query, which here is the expected behaviour, but not in the Spring Boot Backend. A few days ago there was no discrepancy between the two, but suddenly there is. I did nothing in between, no change in the query, no library or server updates or anything. The logs created (Logs->[tab]collecting information  ) don’t reveal any obvious errors to me.

Does anyone has an idea what this behaviour could be caused by or where to look into it?

--

[Question was also posted at the couchbase forum](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/timeout-via-spring-boot-data-couchbase-but-fast-expected-response-via-workbench/18515)

Comment: Have you run an EXPLAIN on the query through both paths and compared the plans?

Comment: When you say "A few days ago there was no discrepancy between the two", it looks like there might be some difference in the environment where your app or couchbase are hosted. Some firewall restrictions maybe which causes the timeout?

Comment: Can you try it by removing the index and creating the index again? Would need to narrow down on the possible causes.

Comment: I have rebuild the index, no changes. The environment is a dedicated server, I changed nothing on that server. Other queries runs without problems.